# In C, is there a variable type that can store bitwise operation results?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, stat

I'm just wondering if there's a variable type I can use to store the result of a bitwise operation. Here's a snippet of what I have:

```
struct stat fileinfo;

if((fileinfo.st_mode & S_IFMT) == S_IFREG){ return FTYPE_REG; }
else if((fileinfo.st_mode & S_IFMT) == S_ISDIR){ return FTYPE_DIR}
```

The part, `fileinfo.st_mode & S_IFMT`, is repeated quite a lot in the rest of my code, so ideally I want to store it in a variable but I'm not too sure what type it would be.

Is it possible to store this as a variable, and if so, what type?

Comment: the result type of bitwise ops is the same as any of the usual arithmetic ops.

Comment: Don't worry about storing it. Modern compilers will cache it for you.

Comment: See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_stat.h.html : `mode_t st_mode`

Comment: @PSkocik Good to know, thanks! Still out of curiosity now and for making my code a little less cluttered, would the type be 'stat'?

Comment: No. There's no type named `stat` (unless you define one yourself). There's a type named `struct stat`, but it's a structure type.

Comment: No. mode_t is a typedef of an integer type and the S_IFMT is of some integer type. These two types will combine according to the rules for arithmetic conversion to give the resulting integer type. By looking at the POSIX spec, an int or an unsigned should suffice.

Comment: You can also use `S_ISDIR(fileinfo.st_mode)`, which is a little more concise.

Comment: Suggest `switch(fileinfo.st_mode & S_IFMT)` rather than an `if this else if that ...`

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can. The type should be the same as `S_IFMT` or `fileinfo.st_mode` is.

Answer (score 2):

You can include `sys/types.h` and then use:

```
mode_t my_mode = fileinfo.st_mode & S_IFMT;
```

As noted in the [spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_types.h.html), "`mode_t` shall be an integer type."